# Syntax highlighting with C#?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, rider

I installed the last version of Rider to replace Visual Studio that cannot handle the solution (C# solution) I work with:

```
Rider 2017.1 EAP
Build #RS-171.4456.575, built on June 16, 2017
Rider EAP User
Expiration date: July 16, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b17 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1
```

At first launch, I chose the dark window and the ReSharper dark theme; and then I opened the solution. The issue is that there is very few syntax highlighting: comments are in green, some keyword in blue (but `partial` is not colored, for example), and that is all. The names of classes are in same color as the rest (white) albeit all seems correctly configured in the Configuration window.

What can be the problem? Maybe the syntax highlighting is not yet implemented? Everything else work fine, I can find usage, go to declaration, etc. but the lack of coloration is a little bit annoying.

I specify that no color theme brings the full syntax highlighting.

Comment: In File-Settings-Editor-Inspection Settings you can turn of color higlighting, maybe it is off? You can also change your color in the preferences at Editor-color and fonts-general in the drop down menu, maybe there is another scheme that fits you better.

Comment: @Simons0n That's it!! Please add it as an answer. By default, the code is not analysed.

Comment: In my case, you could choose the settings after the first start, it is weird, that you were noch able to do that and that is was turned off by default.

Comment: Thanks!  This is disabled by default still (but really, it should be part of the base, not the "Code Analysis" extra).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspection Settings` you can turn of color higlighting, maybe it is off? You can also change your color in the preferences at `Editor -> Color` and `Fonts -> General` in the drop down menu, maybe there is another scheme that fits you better.

Comment: This is exactly why my syntax wasn't highlighted! Thank you so much!